# Image not showing through css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a cover photo for my website. I am using "background-image" through CSS to link the image.

None of my other photos through css image links are showing up either.

I am positive that the local path is correct. (photo is located in "website name"[where index.html is located]/resources/photos/cover.jpg)

What's weird is that the image shows up correctly when linking through HTML using the same path.

CSS:

```
.cover{
    background-image: url(../resources/photos/cover.jpg);
    height: 34.3rem;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cover">
    <div class="summary">
        <span style="width: 80%;">Delightful Days Daycare
            <p>Where everyday is delightful!</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another note: My css is linked properly through HTML

Comment: Your code looks okay. I don't mean to sound facetious, but is your CSS file in the same folder as the HTML file? If not, then the img path will need to change to accommodate.

Comment: Nope, the html file is located in the main folder while the css is located in a subdirectory of (resources/css/style.css). The img path is correct, no?

Comment: try changing the image path using browser inspect element itself, you can try "background:url(/photos/cover.jpg)" or any other combination. It should work

Comment: Try adding `display` property to the `cover` class and play around with various options of  it.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the image in the inspector and right click `open in new tab` and check whether the image loads or not. You can also view the full URL path and better debug if the URL is correct or not. If it loads it's a problem with the code, if not check the URL and match it with your folder structure.

[image]